# Ordinal-indexed sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, formal-languages, ordinals

My question regards, as the title implies, ordinal-indexed sequences as it seems to be rather hard to find definite details about them.

At first, can I imagine an ordinal-indexed sequence as the following?:

Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal number(0,1,...,$\omega$,$\omega +1$,...). Then an ordinal indexed sequence is simply a function from the associated set of this ordinal to the specific alphabet $\Sigma$, i.e. taking the ordinal as a set of its predecessors, we have $s:\alpha\to\Sigma$.

From this consideration, the would be sequences possible like $010010001...2$ with an infinite sequence $010010001...$ indexed by all finite ordinals and another symbol $2$ at the end indexed by $\omega$. The ordinal of this sequence would then be $\omega +1$.

My second question is more of soft one, as I'm curious about the current research state of these type of sequences and what introduction literature is maybe out there.

Comment: Yes to the first question, but to the second question, what sort of research would you expect to be on this topic?

Comment: I was just curious if there have been some interesting directions mentionable. But yes to the first question is the main answer I needed.

Comment: Much as there is no "theory of sequences" but various elementary theorems or lemma regarding this general notion, I don't think people have devoted time to writing down the basic properties of those ordinal-indexed sequences.

Comment: Still ordinal-indexed sequences of characters can be used to define well-founded trees. For instance surreals can be defined as ordinal-indexed binary sequences with additionnal structure. Cardinal-indexed sequences also appear naturally in the context of ordered topological spaces (or just topological spaces) who can't be studied only with regular sequences, and in valuation-theory through the notion of pseudo-Cauchy sequences. Not to mention ordinal sequences of sets or structures frequently used to construct structures that are maximal in some respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea has not only been considered for ordinals but also for [linear orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order). The research initially focused on extending Kleene's theorem (equivalence between finite automata and regular expressions) and on logical characterizations. For words indexed by the ordinal $\omega$, the theory is mainly due to Büchi [2]. Early works also include [3,4,6], but I strongly recommend the article [1] which treats your question in some detail and contains an extensive bibliography. The book [5] is the reference book on linear orders.

[1] V. Bruyère and O. Carton, [Automata on linear orderings](https://www.irif.fr/~carton/Publications/Linear/Kleene/Scattered/jcss.pdf), *J. Comput. System Sci.* **73**, 1, 1-24, 2007.

[2] J. R. Büchi. On a decision method in the restricted second-order arithmetic. In *Proc. Int. Congress Logic, Methodology and Philosophy of science*, Berkeley 1960, pages 1–11. Stanford University Press, 1962.

[3] J. R. Büchi. Transfinite automata recursions and weak second order theory of ordinals. In *Proc. Int. Congress Logic, Methodology, and Philosophy of Science*, Jerusalem 1964, pages 2–23. North Holland, 1965.

[4] Y. Choueka. Finite automata, definable sets, and regular expressions over ωn-tapes. *J. Comput. System Sci.*, **17**(1):81–97, 1978.

[5] J. G. Rosenstein. Linear Orderings. Academic Press, New York, 1982.

[6] J. Wojciechowski. Finite automata on transfinite sequences and regular expressions. *Fundamenta informaticæ*, **8**(3-4):379–396, 1985.